# drag & drop function after all dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm using query ui for a drag & drop, all my elements have the same class '.draggable' and 'dropzone'. I would like to trigger a function when every element with class .draggable has been dropped. Can someone show me an easy way to do it please?

**HTML**

```
<div id="left-panel">
    <div id="drag-1" class="draggable">dra 1</div>
    <div id="drag-2" class="draggable">dra 2</div>
    <div id="drag-3" class="draggable">dra 3</div>
</div>
<div id="right-panel">
    <div id="drop-1" class="dropzone sekt dropzone ui-droppable"></div>
    <div id="drop-2" class="dropzone sekt dropzone ui-droppable"></div>
    <div id="drop-3" class="dropzone sekt dropzone ui-droppable"></div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
//DRAG CONDITIONS

$("#drag-1").draggable({
    containment: '.zone-container',
    snap: '#drag-1',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
$("#drag-2").draggable({
    containment: '.zone-container',
    snap: '#drag-2',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
$("#drag-3").draggable({
    containment: '.zone-container',
    snap: '#drag-3',
    revert: 'invalid'
});

//DROP & ACTION 
$("#drop-1").droppable({
    accept: "#drag-1",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $('.popup').show();
    }
});
$("#drop-2").droppable({
    accept: "#drag-2",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $('.popup').show();
    }
});
$("#drop-3").droppable({
    accept: "#drag-3",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $('.popup').show();
    }
});
```

Fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/j9Ump/63/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j9Ump/63/

Comment: I need to show the popup once the last drag has been drop please

Comment: update: http://jsfiddle.net/j9Ump/64/

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of number of droppable divs, and decrement the counter on each drop. Validate when counter reaches zero. That means all are dropped. Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/j9Ump/67/

```
//DRAG CONDITIONS
counterForDropped = $("#left-panel").find('.draggable').length;
$("#drag-1").draggable({
    containment: '.zone-container',
    snap: '#drag-1',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
$("#drag-2").draggable({
    containment: '.zone-container',
    snap: '#drag-2',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
$("#drag-3").draggable({
    containment: '.zone-container',
    snap: '#drag-3',
    revert: 'invalid'
});

//DROP & ACTION 
$("#drop-1").droppable({
    accept: "#drag-1",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        counterForDropped--;
        checkLastDrop();
    }
});
$("#drop-2").droppable({
    accept: "#drag-2",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        counterForDropped--;
        checkLastDrop();
    }
});
$("#drop-3").droppable({
    accept: "#drag-3",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        counterForDropped--;
        checkLastDrop();
    }
});

function checkLastDrop() {

    if (counterForDropped === 0) {
        alert('last dropped');
    }

}
```